# Pontuação não retornou mesmo após o post ser removido

Tags: suporte, bug, reputação

Dei downvote em alguma resposta da pergunta abaixo, provavelmente era qualidade ruim ou nem era uma resposta válida, e aparece que foi removida, mas a reputação não foi restaurada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ser visto em outros casos do histórico abaixo(2 respostas removidas por divulgação indevida), as respostas foram removidas e a reputação devolvida em seguida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que aconteceu neste caso?

Comment: Agora que reparei bem, foi tirado -2 e não -1 mas to confuso do motivo q perdi esse ponto sendo q não fui autor da pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qualquer edição feita e aprovada (se você ainda não tiver privilégio de editar com aprovação automática) irá dar o ganho de +2 pontos, no entanto se a mesma publicação for removida esses 2 pontos serão removidos da sua pontuação atual. Então o que ocorreu em:

[image]

Você editou a pergunta, ganhou +2 pontos, mas depois de um tempo o usuário Comunidade (operação automática) removeu a postagem:

[image: imagem da pergunta removida pelo usuário Comunidade]

Ao ser removida os 2 pontos ganhos pela edição foram removidos da sua conta também.

**Observação:** na pergunta, ao qual se refere,  não possui respostas, então o -2 descrito na imagem não tem relação com um downvote. Pessoalmente penso que realmente essa parte de devolver ou remover pontos das contas poderia ser mais descritiva.